# What is the difference between these two types of proofs?

Tags: logic, proof

While employing induction method for proving, is deriving the string(formula) "*F<sub>n</sub> → F<sub>n+1</sub>* " any different from showing that if ***F<sub>n</sub>*** holds true, then so does ***F<sub>n+1</sub>*** ?

By showing I mean that we *use* the expression ***F<sub>n</sub>*** or its consequence in order to derive ***F<sub>n+1</sub>***. It appears to me that both in the end mean the same thing -but I am not sure. Is there any difference meta-mathematically or proof theoretically? (However, it seems to me that when deriving the string(formula) "*F<sub>n</sub> → F<sub>n+1</sub>* " we are operating at a meta level). If the latter can be shown to hold, is it *always* possible to "derive" the formula "*F<sub>n</sub> → F<sub>n+1</sub>*" ?

Comment: No difference...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "Fn→ Fn+1 " : Shouldn't this mean that this holds under "every interpretation"?

Comment: Because I am deriving ***not*** Fn+1, but the string(formula) "Fn→ Fn+1 " *itself*...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - (1) Sure, but keeping aside "amounts" to (saying that we have proved) P → Q. how does one go about deriving the string "P→ Q " itself? (2) Is that equivalent to deriving from empty set so that, ⊢ P→ Q ?

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so that should mean that formula  "P→ Q " is a *logically (universally) valid* FOL formula -decidable by Turing Machine (in appropriate formalism)?

Comment: Fn → Fn+1 is a formula and Fn ⊢ Fn+1 is an inference (proof step). In systems like natural deduction the former is derivable from the later by an explicit rule called implication introduction, and in general classically sound proof systems it is valid by the [deduction metatheorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem#Conversion_from_proof_using_the_deduction_meta-theorem_to_axiomatic_proof). The converse is trivially valid by *modus ponens*. If "holds true" refers to semantic consequence  ⊨ then the move from Fn ⊨ Fn+1 to Fn → Fn+1 is only valid in complete proof systems.

Comment: @Conifold  **"** If "holds true" refers to semantic consequence ⊨ then the move from Fn ⊨ Fn+1 to Fn → Fn+1 is only valid in complete proof systems **"** - is that equivalent to "Fn → Fn+1" being a logically valid (Turing machine decidable FOL) formula?

Comment: A move from a meta statement, like semantic consequence, to a FOL formula can not be made within FOL. But you'll get a valid FOL formula if the semantic consequence holds and the system is complete.

Comment: @Conifold I am sorry, but I am totally lost. (1) " A  move from meta statement, like semantic consequence, to a FOL formula can not be made within FOL" -this follows from undecidability of FOL (Turing's Proof)? And, (2) If within my formalism I can derive the formula (string) "Fn → Fn+1", isn't that equivalent to the formula being universally(logically) valid, and therefore TM decidable?

Comment: The question is the converse: *can* you derive Fn → Fn+1 in your formalism given that it's true semantically that Fn+1 is true whenever Fn is. You can not always, your formalism can be incomplete (not derive some true formulas).

Comment: @Conifold Sure, but if Fn is *always* true, what happens then?

Comment: What difference does it make? Fn+1 would also have to be always true for the semantic consequence to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to page 259-262 of [Turing's paper](https://books.google.it/books?id=5G4Eya27gCgC&pg=PA47), the proof that formula **CF<sub>n</sub>** is provable, for every **n**, is by induction.

It is a meta-theory proof, because it is about *formulas* and their derivability ("provability") in the formal system.

The proof is standard [proof by Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation):

(i) Base case: **CF<sub>0</sub>** is provable.

(ii) Induction step: formula **CF<sub>n</sub> → CF<sub>n+1</sub>** is provable, for every **n**.

Thus, by Induction, we conclude that **CF<sub>n</sub>** is provable, for every **n**.

Now, the issue is: what is the exact meaning of "formula **CF<sub>n</sub>** is *provable*" ?

It is derivable in *predicate calculus*.

See page 259:

> [...] to show that the [Hilbert *Entscheidungsproblem* (the problem asks for an algorithm that considers, as input, a statement and answers "Yes" or "No" according to whether the statement is *universally valid*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem) can have no solution.

> I propose, therefore, to show that there can be no general process for determining whether a given formula **A** of the functional calculus **K** [see David Hilbert's and Wilhelm Ackermann's [*Grundzüge der theoretischen Logik* (1928)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Mathematical_Logic), [**Ch.3**](https://books.google.it/books?id=45ZGMjV9vfcC&pg=PA113)] is provable, i.e. that there can be no machine which, supplied with any one **A** of these formulae, will eventually say whether **A** is provable.

> Corresponding to each computing machine **M** we construct a formula **Un(M)** and we show that, if there is a general method for determining whether **Un(M)** is provable, then there is a general method for determining whether **M** ever prints **0**.

Thus, trying to be more "formal", the result you are referring to amounts to (see ["turnstile" symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol))):

> **⊢<sub>K</sub> CF<sub>n</sub>**, for every **n**,

where **⊢<sub>K</sub> CF<sub>n</sub>** means:

> "there is a derivation of formula **CF<sub>n</sub>** in *functional calculus* **K**."

---

*Additional note*: as said above, the induction is performed in the meta-theory, because it applies to *formulas*.

We have an infinite sequence of formulas: **{ CF<sub>0</sub>, CF<sub>1</sub>, ..., CF<sub>n</sub>, ...}** and we consider the property **P(n)** := "formula **CF<sub>n</sub>** is provable (in functional calculus **K**)".

We prove that **CF<sub>0</sub>** is provable, i.e. that **P(0)** holds, and we prove that: "if **CF<sub>n</sub>** is provable, then also **CF<sub>n+1</sub>** is provable, for **n** whatever".

Thus, applying [Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), we conclude that **P(n)** holds for every **n**, i.e. that:

> "**CF<sub>n</sub>** is provable, for every **n**.

Turing writes "**CF<sub>n</sub> → CF<sub>n+1</sub>** is provable" instead of "if **CF<sub>n</sub>** is provable, then also **CF<sub>n+1</sub>** is provable".

There is no difference; in symbols, from **⊢<sub>K</sub> CF<sub>n</sub>** and **⊢<sub>K</sub> CF<sub>n</sub> → CF<sub>n+1</sub>**, by Modus ponens we have **⊢<sub>K</sub> CF<sub>n+1</sub>**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, Turing's paper is where I am having this doubt. I have one lingering doubt still. Shouldn't we write, in Induction Step: "(ii) Induction step: If CF(n), then CF(n+1) is provable, for every n." because saying that "formula **CF(n) → CF(n+1)** is provable, for every n" is technically wrong until we prove ⊢K CF(n), for every n (which only happens when the proof by induction terminates). (More strictly) we shouldn't because "formula **CF(n) → CF(n+1)** is provable, for every n"  is equivalent to  **⊢K CF(n)**, for every n?

Comment: @Ajax - NOT EXACTLY. **CF(n)** is not the same as **CF(n) → CF(n+1)**. The second one holds also if **CF(n)** is false (see truth table for the conditional (**→**) connective).

Comment: Yes! And this should clear things up: so in the context of this paper, statement "Induction Step: formula **CF(n) → CF(n+1)** is provable, for every n" is not the same as the meaning of  "**⊢K CF(n) → CF(n+1)**, for every n" ?

Comment: @Ajax - NOT SURE TO UNDERSTAND. They are the same; see my answer. "**CF(0)** is provable (in functional calculus K)" means: "**⊢K CF(0)**". **CF(n) → CF(n+1)** is provable means  "**⊢K CF(n) → CF(n+1)**" and  "**CF(n)** is provable (in the functional calculus K), for every n" is "**⊢K CF(n)**, for every n".

Comment: What you have to consider is that **CF(n)** is a formula where **n** is **not** a variable but an "index". Thus, we cannot write the formula **(n)CF(n)** because in the formal system variables range over "objects" and not formulas. This is why the induction is in the meta- (outside the formal system): because only in the meta- we cam speak of formulas (and not numbers).

Answer (score 2):

A quasi-formal representation of mathematical induction can be given as the following:

[image]

The stage that we argue from an arbitrary *k* to its successor, though gives the impression of a logical pattern, is essentially arithmetical (compare this case to the sorites paradox, for instance). Mind you, if it were logical, its consequences would be far more reaching than a vindication of logicism.

Comment: @Ajax I've taken your question on mathematical induction in a general setting by which we ordinarily obtain a material implication at an intermediate step. Each of these three statements, 'T1 → T2', ''T1 → T2 is provable', 'if T1 is provable then T2 is provable' belongs to a distinct logical level and their relationships are not immediate; but have to be shown in a Peano Arithmetic dependent way (as for the present case). See Chapter 2 (titled "Peano Arithmetic") of G. Boolos's "The Logic of Provability" for a thorough examination.